# ASP.NET Powershell publish - get build configuration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, publish

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the build configuration used in msbuild from a powershell script that runs after the publishing process. My publishing profile is called *Publish* and I set the following parameter in *Publish.pubxml* file:

```
    <UsePowerShell>True</UsePowerShell>
```

Which means that after a successful publish msbuild automatically executes *Publish-publish.ps1* powershell script. From within that script I can retrieve the *LastUsedBuildConfiguration* parameter, but it doesn't work if it's overridden by the msbuild like so:

```
    MSBuild.exe /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Publish;Configuration=Release
```

How can I retrieve the value of Configuration parameter from the powershell script?

Full *Publish.pubxml* file: http://pastebin.com/78hW4yeU

Full *Publish-publish.ps1* file: http://pastebin.com/a4rp2wE6

Comment: Do you mean that MSBuild will executes Publish-publish.ps1 automatically after publish successfully with the parameter be set <UsePowerShell>True</UsePowerShell> in the Publish.pubxml file? If yes, could you please sharing us the detail steps to reproduce this issue?